# Usar "select" para condicionar la introducción de fechas

Tags: javascript

Quiero que mediante un `select`, si dice **"vencida"**, sólo permita fechas menores a la actual y, si dice **"vigente"**, sólo permita fechas mayores a la actual. Tengo este código y no se que puedo estar haciendo mal.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var opciones = '';
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  
  var opciones = document.getElementById('vencida').value;
  today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
  
  if(opciones == "Vencida"){    
    document.getElementById("myDate").setAttribute("max", today);
  }else if (opciones == "Vigente"){
   document.getElementById("myDate").setAttribute("min", today);
  }
}
```

```html
Seleccione una opción:<br>
<select name="select" id="vencida" onchange="myFunction()" required>
  <option value="Vencida">Vencida</option> 
  <option value="Vigente">Vigente</option>
  <option value="" selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
</select>
<br><br>
Fecha:<br>
<input type="date" id="myDate" name="bday">
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas el primero es que debes agregar manualmente el `0` cuando el valor de día o mes es menor a 10 debido a que `getMonth()` devuelve únicamente el índice del mes (0 para enero, 1 para febrero, etc).

Lo segundo es que debes remover el atributo contrario según el caso:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var opciones = '';
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  dd = dd < 10 ? '0'+dd : dd;
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
  mm = mm < 10 ? '0'+mm : mm;
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  
  var opciones = document.getElementById('vencida').value;
  today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
  
  if(opciones == "Vencida"){    
    document.getElementById("myDate").removeAttribute("min");
    document.getElementById("myDate").setAttribute("max", today);
  }else if (opciones == "Vigente"){
    document.getElementById("myDate").removeAttribute("max");
   document.getElementById("myDate").setAttribute("min", today);
  }
}
```

```html
Seleccione una opción:<br>
<select name="select" id="vencida" onchange="myFunction()" required>
  <option value="Vencida">Vencida</option> 
  <option value="Vigente">Vigente</option>
  <option value="" selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
</select>
<br><br>
Fecha:<br>
<input type="date" id="myDate" name="bday">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba, no sabía que era necesario lo del indice y lo de remover el atributo, he  aprendido algo nuevo, muy amable.

Comment: @RafaelGaitan claro, imagina que te equivocas en la selección del select y terminas usando las dos opciones en cuestión de segundos, tendrás los atributos min y max al mismo tiempo lo que generará que la única fecha que puedas seleccionar es el día actual

Comment: mira que lo estaba implementando y me surge un error y no me toma el atributo hasta que se selecciona 2 veces, aparece: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null.

Comment: @RafaelGaitan puede ser que tu document.getElementById("myDate") no está trayendo nada revisa el selector... recuerda que el id debe ser unico si tienes varios id iguales cambialos

Comment: No, ya lo revisé varias veces, pero todo está bien, y sigue apareciendo eso. Tiene algo que ver que esté usando vue.js?

Comment: ya lo resolví, era solo un setTimeout y ya, gracias...